# Using Bus.Send() and using API services inside Saga Handler

Tags: c#, architecture, event-sourcing, saga

I have this Saga class code below and the question part is commented inside the code. Please mind the simplification of the code as I remove the ubiquitous languages and other details to make it easy to read.

```
public class MessageSaga : Saga,
    IPointBy<SendMessageCommand>, IHandle<RequestProcessingCommand>
{
    private readonly IServices _services;

    public MessageSaga(IServices services,
        IBus bus, IEventStore eventStore, IRepository repository)
        : base(bus, eventStore, repository)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    public void Handle(SendMessageCommand message)
    {
        var msg = MessageAggregate.CreateNew(message.Id, message.Text);
        Repository.Save(msg);

        // This is my Question #1
        var request = new RequestProcessingCommand(message.Id, message.Text);
        Bus.Send(request);
    }

    public void Handle(RequestProcessingCommand message)
    {
        var item = Repository.GetById<MessageAggregate>(message.Id);

        // This is my Question #2
        var result = _services.ProcessMessage(message.Text);
        var response = ProcessItem.Generate(item, result );
        Repository.Save(reponse);
    }
}
```

So, in the code above, I have two questions:

In question number 1, since the "Bus" is available in the Saga class, is this the right way to use Bus.Send() to link to other handler or should I make this inside the Aggregate class?

As in question number two, I have this "_services" Web API outside the domain, is this the right way to use it inside the handler, or should I make this inside the Aggregate classes as well.

All of the my codes works perfectly and I even do load test without any issue. Somehow, I feel doubt as the handler suppose to be simple event saving. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to keep infrastructure concerns *outside* of your domain model (aggregates).  Think [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/).  The basic notion is that the model api creates a boundary between the model and the context it is running in.

Consider: if you start introducing bus or _service into your domain model, any testing of your domain logic requires test doubles that you don't necessarily care about when trying to evaluate your business logic.